# Proving that a matrix has a unique inverse (if it has one).

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to prove that a matrix $A$ can only have a unique inverse.

My proof:

> Let $B$ and $B'$ be inverses of $A$. Then $AB=AB'=I$. Multiplying $A^{-1}$ on the left on both sides (doesn't matter if you take $B$ or $B'$), you get $IB=IB'$. Therefore, $B=B'$.

The argument that Artin has is a little more contrived. I was wondering why this proof wasn't given, considering it is so direct and elementary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haha I agree my question is incomplete. But adding his proof would not contribute in any way to whether **my** proof is correct/incorrect. As for the contrived nature of Artin's proof, you'd have to take my word for that I guess. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that at this level in his book Artin didn't yet use the fact if a matrix has a right inverse then it has an inverse so I think that you can't assume that $A^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: I think by "$B$ and $B'$ are inverses of $A$", he meant they're two-sided inverses.

Comment: Actually I disagree that adding his proof would not contribute. For anyone unfamiliar with the book, it would shed light onto _his_ definitions and assumptions, which may be significantly different than yours. Hence your confusion.

Answer (score 5):

it is contrived because you cannot use a matrix  $A^{-1}$ in your proof - what should it be?

All you know is that there are two matrices $B,B'$ such that
$$
\text{$AB=I$   or  $BA = I$}\\
\text{$AB'=I$ or $B'A=I$}
$$
claim: $B=B'$

proof: $B=BI=BAB'=IB'=B'$

Comment: "AB = BA = I" is only generally true for square matrices and their inverses. Pages 6-7: https://solisinvicti.com/books/TheOlympiad/Books/AlgebraArtin.pdf